# Suppress the serviceList in axis2

Tags: security, jboss, apache-axis

I want to hide the serviceList of axis2.
After googling I found `disableServiceList` is set `true` for hiding the webservicelist

Axis2.xml

```
<axisconfig name="AxisJava2.0">
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!-- Parameters -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <parameter name="hotdeployment">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="hotupdate">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="enableMTOM">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="enableSwA">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="disableServiceList">true</parameter>
.
.
.
.
</axisconfig>
```

After adding this and restarting the server it gives me error like 
`XML document must have a top level element. Error processing resource`

Is there is any wrong with current config or any other way to achive this??

Comment: The issue is related to your XML document. You must close the tags that you have opened in your document. Please double check the document.

Comment: I have cross checked it, by opening xml file in `internet explorer`. and online xml validator. the xml is proper